# insert null values into database when a particular combobox item is selected

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

When I select a particular combobox item i want to enter null values in the database so that I can get the rowcount for that column leaving the null row

```
String bnn = (txtboxno.getText().trim() == null || 
              txtboxno.getText().equals("")) ? "null" : txtboxno.getText();
Object nsn = (cbnotstat.getSelectedItem() == null || cbnotstat.getSelectedItem().equals("")) ? "0" : cbnotstat.getSelectedItem();

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select COUNT(box_no)as total from soil_det WHERE rm_id = ?");
ResultSet rs;
String rm = tf_rm_id.getText();
stmt.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(rm));
rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    tf_boxno.setText(rs.getString("total"));
}
```

I have tried above but it's showing for inputstring "null" error.

Comment: Can you post the exact error string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

similarly you need to check for rm_id

```
String rm = tf_rm_id.getText();
rm = rm == null || rm.isEmpty() ? 0 : rm ; // consider 0 is valid here
long value ;
try {
  value = Long.parseLong(rm) ;
  stmt.setLong(1, value);
} catch(NumberFormatException  ee) {
  System.out.println("Praser exception, invalid input");
}
```